# .Net Core 3.1 Authentication/authorization issue

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-3.1

Hej,
I have a web application, but I seem to be trouble accessing the graph api.

Scenario: I have a web app, where the user logs in and authenticates. Generated a access token etc.

Now I have a backend which requires access to the microsoft graph on behalf on whoever called the endpoint, but I just cant seem to get it to work.

I am working based on the example given here: https://damienbod.com/2020/11/20/using-microsoft-graph-api-in-asp-net-core/

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddScoped<GraphApiClientDirect>();

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                // add JWT Authentication
                var securityScheme = new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Name = "JWT Authentication",
                    Description = "Enter JWT Bearer token **_only_**",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Id = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                    }
                };

                c.AddSecurityDefinition(securityScheme.Reference.Id, securityScheme);
                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {securityScheme, new string[] { }}
                });

                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "gtm_backend", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<Type>, TypeRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRepository<Location>, LocationRepository>();

            // Automapper setup
            GenerateAutoMapperSetup(services);
        }
```

**Configure**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext context)
        {

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "backend v1"));

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            SeedInitialData.Initialize(context).Wait();
        }
```

**GraphApiClientDirect**

```
    public class GraphApiClientDirect
    {
        private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

        public GraphApiClientDirect(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition,
            IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
        {
            _clientFactory = clientFactory;
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }

        public async Task<User> GetGraphApiUser()
        {
            var graphclient = await GetGraphClient(new string[] { "User.ReadBasic.All", "User.Read" })
               .ConfigureAwait(false);

            return await graphclient.Me.Request().GetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private async Task<GraphServiceClient> GetGraphClient(string[] scopes)
        {
            var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(
             scopes).ConfigureAwait(false);

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(client)
            {
                AuthenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                async (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                })
            };

            graphClient.BaseUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta";
            return graphClient;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TESTController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly GraphApiClientDirect _graphApiClientDirect;
        public TESTController(GraphApiClientDirect graphApiClientDirect)
        {
            _graphApiClientDirect = graphApiClientDirect;
        }

        [HttpGet("TESTTESTTEST")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TESTTESTTEST()
        {
            var data = await _graphApiClientDirect.GetGraphApiUser();
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
```

Calling the endpoints always returns a 401

If i remove the policy from my controllers and remove [authorize]

```
services.AddControllers();
```

Calling the endpoints returns a object not set to an instance of an object
on the first line of GraphApiDirect.getGraphClient... var token = ...

Does anybody know whats going on/what my issue is?

The app registration has the required permissions to read the /me endpoint.
I am pretty sure the access token I am sending is correct, I am generating it from postman based on clientid/secret, scopes and /oauth2/token endpoint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try to check your token using website https://jwt.io/ ?

Comment: If you're testing on Swagger, make sure your HTTP requests are indeed sent with your token, your OpenApi config seems a bit off but I might be wrong.

Comment: @serge Hej, I checked the token, and it seems to be right, it has the correct scopes etc

Comment: And how your code is generating token? I can't  see any issiuer, audience ,claims and so on